# Filepicker.io - Multiple not working, and not getting success callback

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I've just started working with filepicker.io

I have this:

```
   'focus #attachment' : function() {
       filepicker.pickAndStore({
        mimetype: "image/*",
        folders: { location: "S3" },
        access: 'public',
        multiple: true
       },
       function(InkBlobs){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(InkBlobs));
       },
       function(FPError){
           console.log(FPError.toString());
       });
   }
```

For the success function, I'll need to have the JSON array to do some database work. Here's where I'm lost:

1. The multiple: true doesn't seem to work. I can still only select a single file.
2. The file is uploading to S3 properly, but I'm getting nothing in the console.log call.

Thank you for your help S.O.

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker pickAndStore function have also storeOptions argument:

```
filepicker.pickAndStore(picker_options, store_options, onSuccess(InkBlobs){}, onError(FPError){})
```

That's why you didn't get anything in the console.
Location and store attributes belongs to store_options. Try this:

```
'focus #attachment' : function() {
  filepicker.pickAndStore({
        mimetype: "image/*",
        folders: true,
        multiple: true
    },
    {
        access: 'public',
        location: 'S3' 
    },
    function(InkBlobs){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(InkBlobs));
    },
    function(FPError){
        console.log(FPError.toString());
    }
);
}
```